# How to achieve parallel bean initialization in Spring Boot

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, spring-jms

I am trying to write a small Spring Boot application using JMS. I have a bean which initializes JMS connection and there are 2 other classes (with their corresponding beans) - a sender and a receiver class using the same JMS topic for the send/receive purpose. It's a single JMS connection being used for both sender and receiver class.

Spring app initializes successfully, but I am only able to run either the sender bean or the receiver bean. How do I make sure that both beans are initialized and may run as independent threads with out any dependency or any references from within the code of one to another?

In other words, after the JMS connection bean is ready I want the sender and receiver beans to be initialized as 2 different and independent threads running unknown to each other. How do I achieve this?

Comment: You'd have to post a code example to get help, but your terminology or understanding is off. Beans are not assigned to threads, for example even though there is generally a singleton of each controller 2 different threads could access that bean instance to respond to 2 different requests. In general beans are thread safe if written correctly.